# In what ratio should I buy options to preserve the diversification effect of the underlying stock portfolio?

Tags: portfolio, option-strategies, diversification

I want to invest in a certain stock portfolio using long down-and-out barrier options. But I am not sure in what ratio to buy the barrier options to retain the same exposure to the volatility of the underlying stocks. Suppose that an XYZ stock portfolio contains 20% company X, 30% company Y and 50% company Z. The aim is to retain the diversification effect of the portfolio, yet leverage the investment. **In what ratio should I buy the barrier options to preserve the diversification effect of the underlying stock portfolio?** The barrier options do not expire unless the stop-loss barrier is hit.

My reasoning is as follows, but I am not sure if this is correct. Let:

```
p = Option price

S = Stock price

F = Financing level. So that:

p = S - F
```

As a result, when buying the option you own the following fraction of the underlying stock:

```
own = p / S
```

So my sense is that the investment would be as follows:

```
investment = (weight / own) * p
```

This means I would end up with the following numbers. I not sure whether this is correct though. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Your guess is as good as anyone's.  There is absolutely no answer to such questions.  There are *buildings* full of PhD analysts who work on this sort of question, and in 100% of cases for 100 years, they consistently, always, every time, without fail - there has never been an exception - lose money like niagra loses water.

Comment: Why is this such a complicated question? I did not realise ... Can you explain the complexity?